# Use up and down keys to set value in a textbox from a table

Tags: jquery, html, netbeans

I have created a table and I am using its content to set the value in a text box. I'm able to do it on mouse click and I'm also able to move up and down the table rows using up and down keyboard keys but I'm not able to set value in the textbox

Here is my code

```
$(window).keyup(function (evt) {
  if (evt.keyCode == 38) { // up
    $('#autotable tr:not(:first).selected')
      .removeClass('selected').prev()
      .addClass('selected');
    $("#textp")
      .val($(this)
      .find('td:first').html()); //this line is not working
  }
  if (evt.keyCode == 40) { // down
    $('#autotable tr:not(:last).selected')
      .removeClass('selected').next()
      .addClass('selected');
    $("#textp").val($(this).find('td:first').html());
  }
});
```

Here is the reast of my code where i have created the table dynamically using ajax

```
   <SCRIPT language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript">
     var xmlHttpRequest=new XMLHttpRequest();
     function edValueKeyPress()
     {
         if(document.getElementById("textp").value!==""){
      xmlHttpRequest.open("get","/WebApplication1/NewServlet?id=" + document.getElementById("textp").value,true);
     xmlHttpRequest.onreadystatechange=process;
     xmlHttpRequest.send();
         }
         else
             {
                 var table=document.getElementById("autotable");
                 table.innerHTML="";
             }
     }

     function process()
     {

                 var JSONtopicobject=eval( "("+xmlHttpRequest.responseText + ")" );
                 console.log(JSONtopicobject);
                 var table=document.getElementById("autotable");
                 table.innerHTML="";

                 var headrow=table.insertRow(0);
                 var headcell=headrow.insertCell(0);
                 headcell.innerHTML=JSONtopicobject.topic.name;
                 var tutorials=JSONtopicobject.topic.tutorial;
                 var i=0;
                 while(i<tutorials.length)
                     {
                         row=table.insertRow(i);
                         row.className=JSONtopicobject.topic.name;
                         cell=row.insertCell(0);
                         var p=tutorials[i];
                         cell.innerHTML=p.name;
                         ++i;
                     }

     }
          </SCRIPT>
                <style type="text/css">
                        td {  cursor: pointer;}

.selected {
background-color: brown;
color: white;
}

  </style>





</head>

<body >
    <h1 style="background-image:url(320px-Draft01_wkp.png);font-size:400%;color: white;">GetaDictionary.com</h1>
    <form action="/WebApplication1/NewServlet" method="post">
        <input type="text" name="textp" id="textp" value=""  onkeypress="edValueKeyPress();" onkeydown="edValueKeyPress();" onkeyup="edValueKeyPress();"  />
        <input type="submit" name="button1" id="button1" value="SEARCH" />

        <br><table id="autotable" style="border: 1px solid grey;font-size:100%;border-top-color: white;" width="173.5" ></table>
    </form>


</body>
```

Comment: Please click the `<>` button and create a [mcve]